# How to replace recurring by day specific event in fullcalendar?

Tags: reactjs, recurring-events, fullcalendar-4

I have set user's availability by recurring event for every Sunday that user is not available. If the user provides data for specific Sunday that he/she is available for particular Sunday than how can I replace that recurring event for that particular day by that specific day event.

Please help me out.
For example :

```
const events = [
        {
            title: 'Not Available',
            allDay: true,
            dow: [0,6],
            type: 'general',
            // className: 'unavailable',
        },
        {
            title: 'Available',
            allDay: false,
            start: '2019-02-02',
            end: '2019-02-02',
            type: 'specific',
            // className: 'unavailable',
        },
    ];
```

In this example user is not available for all sunday and saturday but on specific saturday dated as "2019-02-02" he/she available than i want to show only specific event not recurring event.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: additional array for special available days?

Comment: array is in format as i showed in example

Comment: another array in your array.. `extradaysAvailable: { '2019-XX-XX' , '2019-YY-YY' , '2019-ZZ-ZZ' }`

Comment: couldn't get you. can you please elaborate it?

Comment: You have an array where each entry holds availability for a person. This entry has information for `start date` and `end date` and the `days of the week` when the person is available. Now you can add another entry `specialDays` or `extraDays` or whatever you choose to name, which shall be an array holding dates of the days where the person is available even though by default that person isn't available on those days.